# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I know this is a common problem but don't know what's wrong here. As you can see there's this `//return $user` and it shows an valid id. Checked that in database as well.

```
        $user = new User;
        $user->first_name           = $data['first_name'];
        $user->last_name            = $data['last_name'];
        $user->email                = $data['email'];
        $user->phone_no             = $data['phone_no'];
        $user->created_from         = 'Web App';
        $user->save();
        // return $user;
        Session::put('user_id',$user->id);
        // return $user->id;
        $address = new Address;
        $address->user_id           = $user->id;
        $address->first_name        = $data['receiver_first_name'];
        $address->last_name         = $data['receiver_last_name'];
        $address->email             = $data['receiver_email'];
        $address->address_line_1    = $data['receiver_address_line_1'];
        $address->address_line_2    = $data['receiver_address_line_2'];
        $address->landmark          = $data['receiver_landmark'];
        $address->pincode           = $data['receiver_pincode'];
        $address->phone_no          = $data['receiver_phone_no'];
        $address->created_from      = 'Web App';
        $address->save();
```

Here are the migrations:
This is the users migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('phone_no', 20)->nullable();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->string('remember_token', 100);
        $table->date('date_of_birth')->nullable();
        $table->string('created_from');

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

}

***Addresses***

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('addresses', function($table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('address_line_1');
        $table->string('address_line_2')->nullable();
        $table->string('landmark')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->string('state')->nullable();
        $table->string('phone_no', 13);
        $table->integer('pincode');
        $table->string('created_from');

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

Here's a screenshot of error if it helps.
[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Does it fails at `$address->save()` or at `$user->save()` ? Show us the table definition for user and address.

Comment: fails at `$address->save()`

Comment: This is a shared code and dunno how but somehow the other guy has made reference to `src` instead of `users`. Will have to edit all tables now. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, your error is caused by inserting a value in adresses.user_id (FK to src.id), which does not exist in src.id.

In the example, you try to insert 29 in adresses.user_id, check if `SELECT id FROM src WHERE id=29` returns any result. If not, there is your problem.

Comment: This is a shared code and dunno how but somehow the other guy has made reference to `src` instead of `users`. Will have to edit all tables now. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
```

but

```
$table->increments('id');
```

Should be the same: unsigned

Keys should be the same types of data

Comment: Doesn't that mean one and the same?

Comment: You need $table->increments('id')->unsigned(); for migration.

Comment: To be sure please check in db 
id and user_id should be integer , same size (for example 10) and unsigned