# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails Yii2

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2

I knew there are a lot of questions the same, but I couldn't find useful information. The answers in other questions is saying that the value doesn't exist in another table, but I didn't understand it. In my case I guess all the values are correct:

This is my `item` database:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`price` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

 --
 -- Indexes for dumped tables
 --

  --
  -- Indexes for table `item`
  --
ALTER TABLE `item`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ADD KEY `fk-sale-category_id` (`category_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `item`
--
ALTER TABLE `item`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
--
-- Apribojimai eksportuotom lentelėm
--

--
-- Apribojimai lentelei `item`
--
ALTER TABLE `item`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk-sale-category_id` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

And this is my `category` database:

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `category`
--
ALTER TABLE `category`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `category`
--
ALTER TABLE `category`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=15;
```

My Yii2 `SiteController` action:

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
    $category = new Category();
    $category->scenario = Category::SCENARIO_CREATE;
    $item = new Item();


    if ($category->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $item->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($category->validate(false) && $item->validate(false)) {
                   $item->category_id = $category->id;
        return $this->redirect(['create']);
    }
}
    return $this->render('create', [
        'category' => $category,
        'item' => $item,
        ]);
    } 
}
```

In `item` database there is `category_id`, which has a foreign key, but that value is in `category` also, it's `id'. I hope you understand it, thanks for any help

Comment: sql or mysql database?

Comment: @reds "ENGINE=InnoDB" = definitely MySQL.

Comment: thanks @Anthony Horne.. i don't understand what he is doing? updating a record value in hes database or just creating a foreign key..

Comment: @reds I'm trying to create a form which includes different tables, but I get that kind of error. I checked the answers and all the answers said that the problem is with the tables

Comment: what do you mean form? First thing you have to do is.. if you want to update or insert a record into a foreign key table make sure that you have that value from your Primary key table..

Comment: You need to show us Yii2 code that perform insert/update to the database. See [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798588/sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-chi?rq=1)

Comment: try to follow to @putu link

Comment: @putu answer updated.

Comment: Make sure the value is exists in your primary key table before you insert a record into your foreign key table @MKD. Hope it helps

Comment: This line: `Yii::$app->request->post()` may causing the problem. You assign the whole data in `POST` to both of `category` and `item`. You need to separate which `POST`s item is belong to `category` etc. See [this guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html) on how to construct model using Form data (Massive assignment part)

Comment: forign key is preventing data to update . you need to change category id column structure . youhave to change  ONUPDATE or on DELETE field  to NO ACTION